# css conditional styling based on number of elements

Tags: css

In my react js project

There is a block which may have one element or two elements, depending on run time.

For example:

Scenario 1: **(two groups are existed )**

```
<div class='menu-list'>
    <div class='group'>
        <div class="option">....</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='group'>
        <div class="option">....</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Scenario 2: **(only 1 group)**

```
<div class="menu-list">
    <div class='group'>
        <div class="option">....</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Original I have my css styling ready. However, I noticed there exist scenario 2 sometimes in run time and I dont want to apply any styling in this situation.

I would like to style the element only when it is in scenario 1.

**.menu-list .group:first-child .option:last-child { .....}**

If it is possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have these two scenarios: when it's one element you apply one specific style, when it's multiple elements you apply another style, this should be for you.

```css
.group {
    color:green;
}
.group:first-child:last-child {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu-list'>
    <div class='group'>
        <div class="option">If the element is not alone, it's green</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='group'>
        <div class="option">If the element is not alone, it's green</div>
    </div>
</div>

---

<div class="menu-list">
    <div class='group'>
        <div class="option">If it's alone it's red</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or, if you only need to style for the first scenario (multiple elements)

```css
.group:not(:first-child:last-child) {
   color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu-list'>
    <div class='group'>
        <div class="option">If the element is not alone, it's green</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='group'>
        <div class="option">If the element is not alone, it's green</div>
    </div>
</div>

---

<div class="menu-list">
    <div class='group'>
        <div class="option">If it's the only element, I don't apply the style</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As rightly suggested by @AmauryHanser, using `:only-child` is more correct

```css
.group:not(:only-child) {
   color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu-list'>
    <div class='group'>
        <div class="option">If the element is not alone, it's green</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='group'>
        <div class="option">If the element is not alone, it's green</div>
    </div>
</div>

---

<div class="menu-list">
    <div class='group'>
        <div class="option">If it's the only element, I don't apply the style</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First, thanks for you answer and time. May I ask how do u set a condition to not to apply style when there is only one group ?

Comment: Instead of using `:first-child:last-child`, you could use `:only-child`.

Comment: Sorry , i dont understand how to place it with :only-child and achieve target in this context? would you kindly provide example?

Comment: @AmauryHanser I didn't know that, thanks. For `user21357723` It's too long for a comment, but I invite you to look at these guides for CSS selectors [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) / [:only-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) / [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) / [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

Comment: @user21357723 I've updated the answer with `:only-child`, but I suggest you read the links I wrote you in the previous comment, it's more useful than achieving the goal.

Comment: @Baro , thanks for reference, I am still figuring it out by seeing examples. 
In the meanwhile,  I only want to highlight the last option ... not the whole group... If it is still work in your example?

Comment: Here is what i tried, 
_group:not(:only-child):first-child  .option:last-child) {
   color: green
  }

seems odd, not sure which part goes wrong @Baro

Comment: @user21357723 All 3 work, but the first one in particular is the trickier one (requires you to use the same styles, because it overrides the styles) use `:only-child`, it's the most correct. Trust me, don't try, you have to understand the logic, otherwise you won't get out! Even easier [:not](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.php) and [:only-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_only-child.php)

Comment: ok, thank you for your time. I will continue to work on it. 
but could you kindly point out why I cant make the last element in green when there is not only child? I base it on your example?

.group:not(:only-child) {
  .option:last-child {
    color:green;
  }
}
@Baro

Comment: I mean i only want the last If the element is not alone, it's green in the group to be highligted, not every "If the element is not alone, it's green" ; This is more close to my original question or actually same thing can apply

Comment: @user21357723 Do you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/mpv41o5L/

Comment: yes similar, ..... css sytax are so difficult to make sense ... need to keep try and error.  it is so hard to get it right

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers and adjustment,

this logic gets to the target.

```
.group:not(:only-child):first-child .option:last-child{

     color:green;
  
}
```

Thank you all